# Cycle2 showing previous div's background

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-cycle2

I have a problem with Cycle2. I have 3 divs:

- **First div** has a background image
- **Second div** has a youtube embedded video
- **Third div** has nothing but text

No matter what slide is active, I constantly see the **First Div**'s background.

So, you problably wan't to see the code:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div class="cycle-slideshow"
        data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz"
        data-cycle-timeout="0"
        data-cycle-next="#next"
        data-cycle-prev="#prev"
        data-cycle-pager=".pager"
        data-cycle-slides="> div"
        data-cycle-youtube="true"
        data-cycle-youtube-autostart="false"
        data-cycle-auto-height="false">
        <div class="">ALL CONTENT GOES IN DIVS HERE</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A few screenshots: 
[image: First Div]
[image: Second Div]
[image: Inspect Code]

My little investigation told me it was the Sentinel div which Cycle2 creates, a quick fix for that was adding **data-cycle-auto-height="false"** but apparently I didn't help in my case.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the Sentinel slide will sometimes mess up its opacity. I added the following style and it seemed to help.

I added the following style:

```
.cycle-sentinel {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

I alseo set the embedded youtube's url to include a `&wmode=transparent`